# Block port on docker host

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

I have an ubuntu vps and use it to mostly run bunch of docker containers. However one service (which collects metrics from the host machine) is running on host itself. How can I block access to its port from everywhere except from docker? I stitched together

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i '!docker0' -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
```

(docker docs tells to use DOCKER-USER to setup rules that are executed before other docker's autosetup rules)

but this doesn't block anything, I can still access the port from the internet. I didn't set up any other rules myself. Most answers I find tell "remove 'allow all' rules", but I didn't create and I don't see anything like this if I run iptables-save

Comment: Place the exclamationmark like this: `! -i docker0`

Comment: didn't help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I don't know iptables well, and docker docs misguided me. DOCKER-USER replaces FORWARD only (and for whatever reason I assumed it was for everything); I should have just used INPUT instead